# get dat from cursor to arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with 10 columns.

```
String createQuery = "  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (
                        _id integer primary key autoincrement,
                        name text, 
                        longi real, 
                        lati real, 
                        vibration integer, 
                        sound integer, 
                        brightness integer, 
                        mdata, 
                        bluetooth, 
                        wifi);";
```

How can I get all table data in an `ArrayList`?

Comment: i didn't write any code for that, i have to use arraylist, but i dont know how to use it

Comment: i tried to put in a string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things. You need to create a sub-class of `SQLiteDatabase`. Once you have that, you can get run a query inside a method in this class like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query("profile", // table name
    new String[] { // columns
                    "_id",
                    "name",
                    "longi",
                    "lati",
                    "vibration",
                    "sound",
                    "brightness",
                    "mdata",
                    "bluetooth",
                    "wifi"
                }, 
    null, null, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Long id = cursor.getLong("_id");
    String name = cursor.getString("name");
    // and so on, list of your columns you want to get.

    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Obviously you won't be able to put one whole row into an array list because you have different column types. But you can process one row at a time inside the `while` loop after you get all the values.

Most of this info is taken from here, which is a great source of info:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: @ahmed if this answer is helpful to you, please click the checkmark to the left of it so it gets marked as the correct answer. Thanks.